# Passing variable containing a url to an ajax with cakephp leads to error

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

Everything is going well with my ajax code when passing variables, lets say "hello world" but when passing a variable containing such as "hello world http//www.facebook.com" leads to many problems actually.

Actually its the variable "new_textarea" that I am having problem with.
To clarify things out say,

```
var new_textarea = "hello world"; //successfully saves it to database
```

but when

```
var new_textarea = "http://www.facebook.com" // will lead to problems
```

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/learns/quickpostcomment/'+user_discussion_id+'/'+user_id+'/'+new_textarea+'/'+parent_id,
success: function(data){
}});
```

And this is my cakephp:

```
public function quickpostcomment()
{
    $post = $this->params['pass'];
    $this->ClassroomComment->create();
    $this->ClassroomComment->set('classroom_id', $post[0]);
    $this->ClassroomComment->set('user_id', $post[1]);
    $this->ClassroomComment->set('comment', $post[2]);
    $this->ClassroomComment->set('parent_id', $post[3]);
    $this->ClassroomComment->save();
    die;
}
```

So far all that I inspected is that whats triggering the problem is the "/" or slashes on the variables when variables contain a url.

Is there any way I can pass a variable to my ajax containing slashes or url? 
I need help badly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should send a POST request with Ajax instead of a GET. If you build the posted data correctly, you could event get them in your action as you get data from standard Cake forms.

```
jQuery.ajax({   
    url     : "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'learns', 'action' => 'quickpostcomment'), true); ?>,
    type    : "POST",
    cache   : false,
    data    : "data[ClassroomComment][user_discussion_id]=" + user_discussion_id + "&data[ClassroomComment][user_id]=" + user_id + "&data[ClassroomComment][new_textarea]=" + new_textarea + "&data[ClassroomComment][parent_id]=" + parent_id,
    success : function(data){

    }
};
```

The posted data would then be available in you controller in:

```
$this->request->data['ClassroomComment']
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! this is what I came up with $.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: '/learns/quickpostcomment/',
  data: "data[ClassroomComment][user_discussion_id]=" + user_discussion_id + "&data[ClassroomComment][user_id]=" + user_id + "&data[ClassroomComment][new_textarea]=" + new_textarea + "&data[ClassroomComment][parent_id]=" + parent_id,
  success: function(data){
   
   alert("Okay!");
  }

Answer (score 2):

Try using `encodeURIComponent()` around your variable `new_textarea`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/343465) for more information on using `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent`.

In your `quickpostcomment()` action you may need to use the [urldecode()](http://php.net/urldecode) function on `$post[2]`. I can't remember if cake does this automatically for you, but I doubt it does.